# Is there a way to go through all my functions and see which variables were not declared correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function findCount(req,res, s){
     count = s.length; //count was not initialized! Causes problems.
     res.send(count);
}
```

In Node.js, this code causes problems when there are a lot of hits, since I didn't add "var" before count.

I'm afraid that I forget to add `var` to initialize my variables.

Is there a way to scan my code and determine, for each function, which variables were not initaizlied?

**Better yet: Is there a way to automatically initialize all variables inside each function?**

Comment: How much code is there? A visual scan or a search in your text files wont work?

Comment: A lot of code, so I don't want to visually go through each line to see which didn't get initialized.

Comment: Do you guys know what I'm talking about? (the problem that not initializing causes)

Comment: @Owalla you realise you have the bigger problem of not having learned JavaScript properly before starting node. That's going to bite you in the ass later, I recommend you pick up some learning resources on js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used JSLint? It parses J-script for you, it's very useful.  You can find the online version [here](http://www.jslint.com/).

It would give you something like :

"Problem at line 1 character 1: 'count' was used before it was defined"

Hope that's what you're after

Comment: The phrase J-Script disgusts me. We write EcmaScript :(, Also if you want a tool that doesn't come with crockfords style opinions try [jshint](http://jshint.com/)

Comment: @Raynos, you do realise you sound like a troll don't you? :P

Comment: The jshint recommendation is serious, jslint has a habit of throwing "errors" if you don't agree with Crockford's code style choicing. And the phrase JScript specifically means the dialect of ECMAScript used by microsoft back in the IE5 and ASP days. Brings back bad memories of the 90s when JScript was bad.

Comment: @Raynos I have an idea: add your own answer. I pasted the above code into JSLint and JSHint and JSHint didn't bother me with things like "use strict;" and adding spaces in between commas.

Answer (score 3):

No. Becuase it depends on the context. For example, you could have a global variable call `count`. Putting `var` inside anything declares it locally.

So just putting the `var` declaration may in fact break your processing meaning that even if you could run a program that picked up undeclared variables, only you the programmer could know the context and the correct place to declare it.

Comment: I don't use any global variables

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/). It automatically adds var declarations. It translates this:

```
findCount = (req, res, s) ->
  count = s.length;  #count was not initialized! Causes problems.
  res.send count
```

Into this:

```
var findCount;
findCount = function(req, res, s) {
  var count;
  count = s.length;
  return res.send(count);
};
```

It's fairly popular in the Node.js community with a number of popular packages on npm, including Zombie.js and riak-js being written in it.